# React - Unable to Download the Current Page as PDF file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to download the current Page as PDF file , But When I click on Download PDF button, I am facing the
below errors, Can anyone help me out to download the current Page as PDF file....
error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Here is the code :

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import axios from "axios";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import "jspdf-autotable";

const ButtonUsage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [showTable, setShowTable] = useState(false);
  const recordsPerPage = 10;
  const pagesToShow = 5;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showTable) {
      getProductData();
    }
  }, [showTable]);

  const getProductData = () => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
    });
  };

  // Calculate the maximum number of pages based on the data
  const maxPages =
    data && data.length > 0 ? Math.ceil(data.length / recordsPerPage) : 1;

  // Change page
  const paginate = (pageNumber) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  };

  // Function to download the current page as a PDF
  const downloadCurrentPageAsPDF = () => {
    console.log("downloadCurrentPageAsPDF function called.");
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
      generatePDF();
    } else {
      console.error("Data is empty or undefined.");
    }
  };

  // Function to generate PDF
  const generatePDF = () => {
    // Create an HTML element to hold the table content
    const tableContainer = document.createElement("div");
    tableContainer.style.width = "100%";
    tableContainer.style.overflow = "auto";

    // Create a table element with the current page's data
    const table = document.createElement("table");
    table.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";
    table.style.width = "100%";
    table.style.marginBottom = "20px";

    const tableHead = table.createTHead();
    const headRow = tableHead.insertRow(0);

    const headers = ["userId", "id", "title", "completed"];

    headers.forEach((headerText, index) => {
      const cell = headRow.insertCell(index);
      cell.textContent = headerText;
      cell.style.border = "1px solid black";
      cell.style.padding = "8px";
    });

    const tableBody = table.createTBody();

    const currentRecords = data.slice(
      (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage,
      currentPage * recordsPerPage
    );

    currentRecords.forEach((row) => {
      const newRow = tableBody.insertRow();
      const rowData = [
        row.userId,
        row.id,
        row.title,
        row.completed ? "Yes" : "No",
      ];
      rowData.forEach((cellData, index) => {
        const cell = newRow.insertCell(index);
        cell.textContent = cellData;
        cell.style.border = "1px solid black";
        cell.style.padding = "8px";
      });
    });

    tableContainer.appendChild(table);

    // Create a PDF document and add the table content
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable({
      html: tableContainer,
    });

    // Save the PDF file with a name
    doc.save("current_page.pdf");
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setShowTable(true)}>
        Get Data
      </Button>

      {showTable && data && data.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table
              sx={{ minWidth: 650 }}
              size="small"
              aria-label="a dense table"
            >
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>userId</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>id</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>title</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>completed</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {data
                  .slice(
                    (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage,
                    currentPage * recordsPerPage
                  )
                  .map((row) => (
                    <TableRow
                      key={row.id}
                      sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
                    >
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {row.userId}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.userId}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.id}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.title}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.completed ? "Yes" : "No"}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
          <div className="pagination">
            <button onClick={() => paginate(1)} disabled={currentPage === 1}>
              First
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => paginate(currentPage - 1)}
              disabled={currentPage === 1}
            >
              Previous
            </button>
            {Array.from({ length: Math.min(pagesToShow, maxPages) }, (_, i) => (
              <button
                key={i + 1}
                onClick={() => paginate(i + 1)}
                className={currentPage === i + 1 ? "active" : ""}
              >
                {i + 1}
              </button>
            ))}
            <button
              onClick={() => paginate(currentPage + 1)}
              disabled={currentPage === maxPages}
            >
              Next
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => paginate(maxPages)}
              disabled={currentPage === maxPages}
            >
              Last
            </button>
            <button onClick={downloadCurrentPageAsPDF}>Download PDF</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ButtonUsage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the length of the array `data`. This problem could occur due to the improper fetch of `data` or it is undefined when you're attempting to download the PDF.

Make sure that the API request is successful and `setData` is being called properly.  Add a `console.log(res.data)` after `setData(res.data)` to check if the data is received properly.